# pthread and UDP

Tags: c, pthreads

I am begining with the pthread library and I would like to execute a function like this several time in parallel :

```
while(true) {
    //Part A
    //do several stuff
    //End of Part A

    //Part B
    //do other stuffs
    //End of Part B
}
```

I can do that easily by lopping on pthread_create(). The problem is that the main program seems to switch thread before the part B is executed. As a result I see part A executed over and over but never part B. Could someone help?

Some actual code =>

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define error(msg) \
        perror(msg); \
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE)


//Declarations
int mastersocket;
struct sockaddr_in addr;
struct hostent *fromhost, *tohost;
int nthread=5;
int  decdomain=13;
long serveurdns=0x0101a8c0;

static void * test(void * p_data) {

    while(1) {
        printf("hello\n");
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

        int k, l;
        pthread_t idt[5];

    //Assignation, mallocs
    //Strings

    //Appel a socket
    if( (mastersocket=socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
        error("socket");
    }

    //Configuration de sockaddr pour l'appel a bind
    addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    addr.sin_port=htons(53);

    //Appel a bind
    if( (bind(mastersocket, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr))) < 0 ) {
        error("bind");
    }

    for(k=0; k<nthread; k++) {

        pthread_create(&idt[k], NULL, mainbis, (void *)mastersocket);

    }
    mainbis((void *)mastersocket);

    return 0;

}

static void * mainbis(void * p_data) {

    int socketh= (int) p_data;
    int found=0, len, cc;
    char *buf, *curfish;
    struct sockaddr_in *from, *to;
    u_long fromaddr, toaddr;
    int lenbuf=5000;

    buf=(char *)malloc(lenbuf);
    curfish=(char *)malloc(100);

    len=sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    to=(struct sockaddr_in *)malloc(len);
    from=(struct sockaddr_in *)malloc(len);
    //Structure sockaddr du serveur DNS vers lequel on redirige les requete
    to->sin_family=AF_INET; 
    to->sin_addr.s_addr=serveurdns;
    to->sin_port=htons(53);

    //Let's go
    while(1) {

        found=0;
        curfish=NULL;
        //Reception des requetes
        if((cc=recvfrom(socketh, buf, lenbuf, 0, (struct sockaddr *)from, &len))<0) {
            error("recv");
        }
        buf[cc]='\0';

        //Identification de l'host appelant
        //fromaddr=(*from).sin_addr.s_addr;
        //fromhost=gethostbyaddr((void *)&fromaddr, sizeof(fromaddr), AF_INET);

        //Sortie utilisateur
        printf("\n\n--   New Request From $$ on Port ... Domain = %s ||\n--  ***********************\n", buf+13);

        curfish=somefunction();
        if( curfish!=NULL ) {

            found=1;

        }

        if(sendto(socketh, buf, cc, 0, (struct sockaddr *)to, len)<0) {
            error("send");
        }

        if((cc=recvfrom(socketh, buf, lenbuf, 0, (struct sockaddr *)to, &len))<0) {
            error("recv");
        }
        buf[cc]='\0';

        printf("\n\n--   New Response From $$ on Port ||\n--  ***********************\n");

        if(found) {

            buf[cc-1]=0x81;
            buf[cc-2]=0x2;
            buf[cc-3]=0xa8;
            buf[cc-4]=0xc0;

        }

        if(sendto(socketh, buf, cc, 0, (struct sockaddr *)from, len)<0) {
            error("send");
        }

    }
    return NULL;

}
```

It's a UDP redirector for DNS request, when I launch and try to use dig for instance, my program always output the "New Request..." string but never the "New Response..." one and dig never get the response.

Jules

Comment: Why not show some actual code?

Comment: Are you printing messages to check order of execution? When you start multi threading it's a good idea to `fflush(stdout)` after each print call to insure messages come out in the correct order.

Comment: What do you mean, "never part B" ? If you stop creating threads, eventually they'll work on part B, except if you have a problem in part A that crashes the thread.

Comment: Some points, first of all you need to `pthread_join` your threads in the end. Second, why do you have 5 threads doing the exact same thing with the same socket? Third, are you sure `recvfrom` and `sendto` functions are thread safe? If not, you need a synchronization mechanism between your threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can't work. You bind 1 socket `mastersocket` , and you create several threads using this socket.

This is by itself ok, but the logic inside mainbis() assumes that it will read a reply to what it sent.
That might not happen, the reply could be read by any of the other threads you create that is blocking in `recvfrom` on that same socket, and the logic falls apart.

Create a new socket in each thread that it uses to communicate with the real dns server, and only use `socketh` to communicate with the clients.

Comment: Thank you I am going to try this out